# user interaction and visit duration is not displaying in Sitecore Experience Profile

Tags: xdb, experience-profile

We have a Sitecore form on our website. We created the custom submit action to identify contact based on the email ID following the [link](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-submit-action-that-updates-contact-details.html).

After creating the custom submit action and mapping it to the form. Once the user submits the form the new record is created the experience profile. but user interaction and last duration time are not displayed in the dashboard.

FYI, we have enabled the following in this file **sc.Xdb.Collection.IndexerSettings.xml**

```
 <IndexPIISensitiveData>true</IndexPIISensitiveData>
  <IndexAnonymousContactData>true</IndexAnonymousContactData>
```

There is no data in the interaction table **[xdbsc_Xdb.Collection.Shard0].[xdb_collection].[Interactions]**

why the user activity is not displaying in the dashboard?

Comment: What is the role of the instance you are submitting the form on? (Ie contentmanagement, contentdelivery or standalone)

Comment: The role we have tried content management and standalone

Comment: Tracking is disabled by default on content management instance. Please try submitting from content delivery instance, then either abandon session or wait timeout, then check to see if data arrives I'm interactions table. Also, you can check siteore/admin/showconfig.aspx to see if tracking is somehow disabled

Comment: I tried to closing the browser and open again and visit the page, submit the form

Comment: Did you try from contentdelivery instance? Also what was value of Xdb.Tracking.Enabled in showconfig.aspx?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue with xDB data. Contact or interaction data does not appear in the collection database until after the session has timed out.

You can refer below steps to validate interactions appear correctly in the collection database.

1. Start `InPrivate browsing` in Firefox or Chrome and visit a few web pages on the site.
2. Find the `SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE` cookie and save the value preceding the pipe. For example, retrieve the value "169e920af41d4960ad9eff4d3260f8d9" from the following cookie "169e920af41d4960ad9eff4d3260f8d9|True".
3. Request the `Abandon.aspx` page to flush the data immediately or close the window and wait for the end of the session.
4. Consider one of the following options:

   - **For Sitecore XP 9.0.0 or higher**, when SQL provider is used, connect to shard databases and run the following query against each of them:

     ```
     SELECT LastKnownContactId  FROM [xdb_collection].[DeviceProfiles]
     WHERE DeviceProfileId = '169e920a-f41d-4960-ad9e-ff4d3260f8d9'
     --id retrieved from Cookie should go here. Add dashes to make the value correct GUID.
     ```

     One of the databases must contain the LastKnownContactId. Use it to retrieve the interaction (it will be in one of the shard databases):

     ```
     SELECT * FROM [xdb_collection].[Interactions] 
     WHERE ContactId = '138E219A-0A5A-0000-0000-05D0EB074C6D'
     -- where 138E219A-0A5A-0000-0000-05D0EB074C6D is the copied LastKnownContactId value.
     ```

**Note:** Check [this](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0977445) article if you are using a different Sitecore version.

Once your collection database is populated with interaction and still issue persists you can try [Rebuild the reporting database](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/rebuild-the-reporting-database.html)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have checked in the table SELECT LastKnownContactId  FROM [xdb_collection].[DeviceProfiles] but there is not data in this table.

Comment: Try to troubleshoot with steps provided in scenario 1 https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0977445